# Wait for async submit form dispatch to finish before proceeding to next line

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a Login form which I want to handle it's submit function and update handlings via redux.

`Login.js:`

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isUserExists = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isUserExists);

  const handleSubmitForm = (vals) => {
    dispatch(isUserExistsByPhoneNumber("Login", vals)).then(() =>
      props.navigation.navigate(isUserExists ? "VerifyAuth" : "Signup", {
        vals: vals,
        sentFrom: "Login",
      })
    );
  };
```

`LoginForm.js:`

```
const LoginForm = (props) => {
  const handleFormSubmit = () => {
    props.submitForm(values);
  };

  const [values, handleChange, handleSubmit] = useForm(handleFormSubmit);

  return (
    <View>
      <Input
        name="phoneNumber"
        value={values.phoneNumber || ""}
        onChange={(name, value) => handleChange(name, value)}
        label="Phone Number"
        keyboardType="number-pad"
      />

      <Button
        mode="outlined"
        onPress={handleSubmit}
        loading={props.submitting}
        disabled={props.submitting}>
        Login
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

`AuthActions.js:`

```
export const isUserExistsByPhoneNumber = (sentFrom, phoneNumber) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: authTypes.GET_IS_USER_EXISTS_REQUEST });
    return authService
      .checkIfUserExists(sentFrom, phoneNumber)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: authTypes.GET_IS_USER_EXISTS_SUCCESS });
        dispatch(setIsUserExists(response));
      })
      .catch((errors) => {
        dispatch({ type: authTypes.GET_IS_USER_EXISTS_ERROR, payload: errors });
      });
  };
};
```

The code is not working, simply because the ".then" after the dispatch at `Login.js` is't waiting for the dispatch to finish before proceeding.

How can I fix this, and read isUserExists data only after the dispatch finished?

If I'll do it with useEffect, will I need to create "isDoneDispatching" prop and navigate only when that prop updates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with moving navigation to `useEffect`.

But it seems that you do not store your `values` in the redux store.

Therefore, you will have to store them in component state in order to pass them to navigation logic

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isUserExists = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isUserExists);

  // store values in component state
  const [values, setValues] = useState(null);
  const [allowNavigate, setAllowNavigate] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmitForm = (vals) => {
    // store values in component state since you do not store them in redux state
    setValues(vals);

    dispatch(isUserExistsByPhoneNumber("Login", vals)).then(() => {
      setAllowNavigate(true);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (allowNavigate) {
      props.navigation.navigate(isUserExists ? "VerifyAuth" : "Signup", {
        vals: values,
        sentFrom: "Login",
      });
    }
  }, [allowNavigate, isUserExists, values]); // track values and isUserExists change

  // ...
};
```

Comment: Will i need to make isUserExists's default val to be null and check inside useEffect if it's not null? Otherwise the useEffect will run on first render before the dispatch ends, which will still not fix the error.

Comment: You are right, this way it will redirect on the first render, my mistake... In this case I would prefer to be clear of my intentions and add a separate state to track this. Please, see the updated unswer